# Using Blender camera Paths in Threejs

Tags: camera, three.js, blender, perspectivecamera

How can one bring Blender camera paths into Blender to use as Camera Paths in Threejs?

Is there a way to import the spline of blender into Threejs for further use as a camera path?

Can threejs extract the points of a blender spline and create the path for its cameras?

Comment: You made any progress ? im in the same situation.